# Avro GenericRecord to nested POJO

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro

Is there a way to deserialize GenericRecord (which I just got from Kafka message) to nested POJO? I am actually tying to deserialize it to Scala's case class but I realize that's even harder. I searched through the internet and it seems everyone was doing it manually. Are you aware of any library which is able to do this?

Comment: Must this be a solution that works at runtime, or is using code generation an option in your scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with this:

```
  def valueAvroDeserializer[A](schemaRegistryUrl: String, targetType: Class[A]): Deserializer[A] = {
val readerSchema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(targetType)
val idSize = 4


val deserializer = new AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer with Deserializer[A] {
    def configure(configs: util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean): Unit =
      this.configure(new KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig(configs))

  def deserialize(topic: String, data: Array[Byte]): A = {
      val bytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(data)
      bytes.get() // skip magic byte
      val schemaId = bytes.getInt()
      val writerSchema = schemaRegistry.getById(schemaId)
      val length = bytes.limit() - 1 - idSize
      val reader = new ReflectDatumReader[A](writerSchema, readerSchema)
      val decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes.array(), bytes.position(), length, null)
      reader.read(null.asInstanceOf[A], decoder)
    }

  def close(): Unit = {}
}
val props = Map("schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistryUrl)
deserializer.configure(props.asJava, false)
deserializer
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty generic codec derivation solution for applicative schemas:

https://github.com/danslapman/morphling

It does not provide "import and use" solution but it does provide a way to write your own codec derivation mechanism for your protocol without messing up with shapeless/magnolia.

Also if you need to deal with binary data, try:

https://github.com/scodec/scodec

It provides pretty scala-way of solving such problems.